# How does python determine to make a new instance of an object or to use an old one?

Tags: python-3.x, computer-science, python-unittest

I want to understand how python determines to make a new instance of an object or to use an existing instance. I've been looking at something that I think is causing me an issue, and I suspect it's because of my lack of understanding of what is happening under the hood.

Consider this example in a dummy.py file:

```
import unittest


class Addition:

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.__a = a
        self.__b = b

    def do_addition(self):
        return self.__a + self.__b


class IsolatedTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def custom_add(self, a, b):
        addition = Addition(a, b)
        print(addition)
        return addition.do_addition()

    def test_case_1(self):
        a = 5
        b = 10
        self.assertEqual(15, self.custom_add(a, b))

    def test_case_2(self):
        a = 20
        b = 15
        self.assertEqual(35, self.custom_add(a, b))

    def test_case_3(self):
        a = 99
        b = 105
        self.assertEqual(204, self.custom_add(a, b))
```

When I print the memory location of the addition objects created, I get three different locations.

```
<dummy.Addition object at 0x02BBBF70>    
<dummy.Addition object at 0x02BBBE20>    
<dummy.Addition object at 0x02BBBEC8>
```

Now, consider a slightly modified version of the same thing.

```
class CombinedTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def custom_add(self, a, b):
        addition = Addition(a, b)
        print(addition)
        return addition.do_addition()

    def test_case_1(self):
        a = 5
        b = 10
        self.assertEqual(15, self.custom_add(a, b))
        a = 20
        b = 15
        self.assertEqual(35, self.custom_add(a, b))
        a = 99
        b = 105
        self.assertEqual(204, self.custom_add(a, b))
```

Here I actually get the same exact memory address for all 3 instances of the addition object.

```
<dummy.Addition object at 0x02BBBF70>    
<dummy.Addition object at 0x02BBBF70>    
<dummy.Addition object at 0x02BBBF70>
```

Can someone help me understand what the difference is here? Thanks as always!

Comment: If two objects have different addresses, that is reasonably conclusive proof that they are different objects.  But if two objects created at different times have the same address, that is not conclusive proof that they are the same object.  I did a test where I created an object, then deleted it, then created another object, and both objects had the same address.  If there is little enough otherwise going on, whatever led the interpreter to locate object1 at some address could lead it to create another object at the same address when object1 is gone.

Comment: Also, this may be a question about the unittest module rather than about Python.  I tested the code you posted with all the unittest parts stripped out and while the objects were at different locations for IsolatedTests and CombinedTests, within each of those, the addresses didn't change.

Comment: I see what you're saying with the maybe it's the unittest module if I just make them regular classes. So, outside of unit testing how does this work? In the isolated one, would you think this is create, destroy, create, destroy, ... and it just keeps using the same memory address? In the case where all of the calls are in one function like in the Combined, would this have something to do with the call stack and therefore I should expect 3 different memory addresses? Wouldn't all 3 need to exist at the same time on the call stack?

Comment: In both cases, whenever the custom_add function runs, it creates an Addition object, which is no longer needed when control leaves the function.  How many layers of calls it took to get there makes no difference.  So in the simple case without unittest, it would not be surprising to find all the objects at the same address.  In neither case is there a need to have three Addition objects existing at the same time.  Probably in the IsolatedTests case, the unittest framework is creating some other objects between tests, so the Addition objects get different addresses.

Answer (score 1):

With the CombinedTests class, three Addition objects in succession are created at the same address.  That does not mean they are the same object.

With the IsolatedTests class, the unittest framework probably creates other objects in between running the three test case functions in the class, so the three Addition objects get created at different locations.

In general, the programmer, not the interpreter, decides whether to create a new object or reuse an old one.  If you want to use an object, it's up to you whether to create one or use one you already have lying around.  You assumed that two objects reported to have the same address at different times were the same object, but that is not how it works.